# Am I making a mistake, because in declaring the variables?

Tags: java, distance, declaration, variable-declaration

My code works. It is giving me the correct result, but I feel I did a mistake because I declare `x1`, `y1`, `x2`, `y2` too often (globally and locally). Am I? If I, however, delete one of the declarations, it does not work anymore. Error message:

> error: cannot find symbol

Maybe someone can explain to me, how I should have solved the problem without declaring `x1`, `y1`, `x2`, `y2` that often.

```
public class Distanz {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double d = 0;
        double x1 = 10;
        double y1 = 8;
        double x2 = 2;
        double y2 = 12;
        berechneDistanzAlsProzedur(x1, x2, y1, y2);
        System.out.print("Distanz von p1 und p2 berechnet mit einer Funktion: " + berechneDistanzAlsFunktion(d));
    }
    public static void berechneDistanzAlsProzedur(double x1, double x2, double y1, double y2) {
        x1 = 10;
        y1 = 8;
        x2 = 2;
        y2 = 12;
        double sqd_d = (x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2);
        System.out.println("Distanz von p1 und p2 berechnet mit einer Prozedur: " + Math.sqrt(sqd_d));
    }
    public static double berechneDistanzAlsFunktion(double d) {
        double x1 = 10;
        double y1 = 8;
        double x2 = 2;
        double y2 = 12;
        double sqd_d = (x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2);
        return (Math.sqrt(sqd_d));
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to calculate the euclidian distance as a function and as a procedure. And print out the result.

Comment: "function" and "procedure" don't have specific meanings in Java. Java has methods only. What exactly do you consider a "function" or " procedure" and where have you got those definitions from?

Comment: You haven't declared anything globally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use the parameters `x1`, `y1`, `x2`, and `y2` instead. Otherwise, your methods will always return the same value regardless of the arguments it was called with.

```
public static void berechneDistanzAlsProzedur(double x1, double x2, double y1, double y2) {
  double sqd_d = (x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2);
  System.out.println("Distanz von p1 und p2 berechnet mit einer Prozedur: "+Math.sqrt(sqd_d));
}
public static double berechneDistanzAlsFunktion(double x1, double x2, double y1, double y2) {
  double sqd_d = (x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2);
  return (Math.sqrt(sqd_d));
}
```

Comment: Nice! Yes, that worked and I think I understand a bit why it is better!

Comment: this is a great answer, i don't know why my mind went to global variables but your way is way cleaner (pun not intended)

Answer (score 0):

You could go simple and declare global variables like this:

```
public class Distanz {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double d = 0;
        berechneDistanzAlsProzedur();
        System.out.print("Distanz von p1 und p2 berechnet mit einer Funktion: "+berechneDistanzAlsFunktion(d));
    }

    static double x1 = 10;
    static double y1 = 8;
    static double x2 = 2;
    static double y2 = 12;

    public static void berechneDistanzAlsProzedur() {
        double sqd_d = (x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2);
        System.out.println("Distanz von p1 und p2 berechnet mit einer Prozedur: "+Math.sqrt(sqd_d));
    }

    public static double berechneDistanzAlsFunktion(double d) {
        double sqd_d = (x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2);
        return (Math.sqrt(sqd_d));
    }     
}
```

Of course, I might not know what you want at all and my answer could be completely useless but I think I answered it pretty well. :D

Answer (score 0):

Below solution can eliminate static declaration and code will look very neat.

```
public class Distanz {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        Point point = new Point(10, 8, 2, 12);
        berechneDistanzAlsProzedur(point);
        System.out.print("Distanz von p1 und p2 berechnet mit einer Funktion: " + berechneDistanzAlsFunktion(point));
}

public static void berechneDistanzAlsProzedur(Point point) {
    double sqd_d = (point.getX1() - point.getX2()) * (point.getX1() - point.getX2()) + (point.getY1() - point.getY2()) * (point.getY1() - point.getY2());
    //This formula is same which you have used in berechneDistanzAlsFunktion method, you can eliminate berechneDistanzAlsProzedur function and directly call berechneDistanzAlsFunktion in main function
    //You can pass different points to validate different result
    System.out.println("Distanz von p1 und p2 berechnet mit einer Prozedur: " + Math.sqrt(sqd_d));
}

public static double berechneDistanzAlsFunktion(Point point) {
    return (Math.sqrt((point.getX1() - point.getX2()) * (point.getX1() - point.getX2()) + (point.getY1() - point.getY2()) * (point.getY1() - point.getY2())));
   }
}
```

Your Point class should be look like this:

```
public class Point {
    private final double x1;
    private final double y1;
    private final double x2;
    private final double y2;

    public Point(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2){
        this.x1 = x1;
        this.y1 = y1;
        this.x2 = x2;
        this.y2 = y2;
    }

    public double getX1() {
        return x1;
    }

    public double getY1() {
        return y1;
    }

    public double getX2() {
        return x2;
    }

    public double getY2() {
        return y2;
    }
}
```

Here Point.java called as Wrapper class, which is holding Points information in this code.

Happy Coding.